# Python - Adding rows to timeseries dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing retail sales data which shows the total number of a product sold each week and the stock left at the end of the week.  Unfortunately, the dataset only shows a row when a product has been sold and the stock left changes.

I would like to bulk out the dataset so that for each week there is a line for each product being sold.  I've shown an example of this below - how can this be done?

As-Is:

```
Week Product Sold Stock
1    1       1    10
1    2       1    10
1    3       1    10
2    1       2    8
2    3       3    7
```

To-Be:

```
Week Product Sold Stock
1    1       1    10
1    2       1    10
1    3       1    10
2    1       2    8
2    2       0    10
2    3       3    7
```

Comment: it took me reading twice to figure: the trick is to generate `2    2       0    10` - a row with zero change in stock, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dataframe using `product` from `itertools` with all the combinations of both columns 'Week' and 'Product' and use `merge` with your original data. Let's say your dataframe is called `dfp`:

```
from itertools import product
new_dfp = (pd.DataFrame(list(product(dfp.Week.unique(), dfp.Product.unique())),columns=['Week','Product'])
                 .merge(dfp,how='left'))
```

You get the missing row in `new_dfp`:

```
   Week  Product  Sold  Stock
0     1        1   1.0   10.0
1     1        2   1.0   10.0
2     1        3   1.0   10.0
3     2        1   2.0    8.0
4     2        2   NaN    NaN
5     2        3   3.0    7.0
```

Now you `fillna` on both column with different values:

```
new_dfp['Sold'] = new_dfp['Sold'].fillna(0).astype(int) # because no sold in missing rows
new_dfp['Stock'] = new_dfp.groupby('Product')['Stock'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
```

To fill 'Stock', you need to `groupby` product and use the method 'ffill' to put the same value than last 'week'. At the end, you get:

```
   Week  Product  Sold  Stock
0     1        1     1     10
1     1        2     1     10
2     1        3     1     10
3     2        1     2      8
4     2        2     0     10
5     2        3     3      7
```

Comment: Side Note: This seems to work as well `new_dfp['Stock'] = new_dfp.groupby('Product')['Stock'].ffill().astype(int)`

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks this is a great solution!  One problem I am experiencing is that not all products are listed in week1, so when we run this code we end up with an empty slot for some products which cannot be filled using ffil

Comment: @user1058210 make sense, and what would you like in this case? if you want 0, I think you can try: `new_dfp['Stock'] = new_dfp.groupby('Product')['Stock'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)` like this, the one not filled by `ffill` should end up to be 0

Comment: @Ben.T Sorry I didn't explain myself properly.  Basically the code fails on the dataset with an error of "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer" - which I think is because of the above.

Comment: @user1058210 indeed I think you are right. but by adding `fillna(0)` before the `astype(int)` as in my previous comment, it should work. I just tried the case you describe by adding a row with a new product number in week 2 and I got your error at first, that is fixed by adding `fillna(0)` before `astype(int)`

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks - How does this work though?  Is it saying ffill everything that you can, and then anything leftover fill as 0 and then convert to integer?  So was it failing on the conversion to integer rather than the the ffil?

Comment: @user1058210 yes it was the `astype(int)` failing as not all the `nan` were replaced using `ffill`. So `ffill` means fill forward (or down) so if a row was created at the first week, nothing above could fill it so it stayed `nan`, raising an error when doing `astype(int)`. Adding `fillna(0)` does replace these `nan` with 0, allowind `astype` working. your understanding was good :)